# Pasting value into R plot title

Tags: r

I would like to paste the value of the mean in a plot title using the title() function.

e.g. title("My plot \n mean = mean(x)")

where x is a numeric vector of observations.

I know how to do this using plot(main = " ... ", ). Simply use paste() or substitute(expression()); however, this doesn't seem work with the title() function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use mtext(...., side = 3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer by @MarcoSandri is correct. The correct way of using the example codes you have written are,

```
title(main= paste("My plot \n mean =", mean(x)))
```

and

```
avg <- mean(x)
title(paste("My Plot \n Mean = ", avg))
```

Answer (score 3):

See this example where `title` works correctly:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(30)

txt <- paste("Mean =", round(mean(x),3) )   

plot(x)
title(main=txt)
```

[image]

Comment: While your solution works in general, when I try title(paste("My Plot  \n Mean = " avg), it doesn't work. Here, avg is a variable assignment for mean(x)

Comment: @JarrettPhillips Could you post a code that reproduces  your problem?